# Authorization Code Flow with PKCE in Swagger UI from an OpenAPI definition

Tags: oauth-2.0, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, api-platform.com

I am building a web API for a single-page application (SPA) where users authenticate through a third-party Authorization Server using the Authorization Code Flow with [PKCE](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636). This API is documented using a generated OpenAPI definition with a Swagger UI interface.

Using API Platform 3.1 (a framework to build web APIs), I was able to configure the authorize button from Swagger UI to behave exactly as I wanted without any Swagger UI customization:

[image: swagger-ui-pkce]

Note that API Platform apparently ["integrates a customized version of Swagger UI"](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/openapi/#openapi-specification-support-formerly-swagger) so the PKCE support could be specific to their Swagger UI version.

However, I am failing to do that using other tools that use a vanilla Swagger UI to use the authorization code flow with PKCE (but I can configure it to use normal authorization code flow without the PKCE extension).

Is the Authorization Code Flow with PKCE something that is available in (vanilla) Swagger UI? Can this authorization method be documented using OpenAPI 3.0?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, vanilla SwaggerUI supports PKCE!

I run SwaggerUI with PKCE in docker with the following command:

```
docker run --rm -p 80:8080 \
-v ~/Desktop/SWAGGER_UI:/foo \
-e SWAGGER_JSON=/foo/my-service-openapi.yml \
-e OAUTH_CLIENT_ID=my-service-client-id \
-e OAUTH_SCOPES="openid offline" \
-e OAUTH_USE_PKCE=true \
swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

(Place your OpenAPI spec in "~/Desktop/SWAGGER_UI/my-service-openapi.yml")

You can see the settings [here](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/oauth2/)

In the OpenAPI Spec you can define it like described [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/oauth2/)!
You have to change to "authorizationCode":

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    oAuthSample:
      type: oauth2
      description: This API uses OAuth 2
      flows:
        authorizationCode:
          authorizationUrl: https://your-host.com/oauth2/auth
          tokenUrl: https://your-host.com/oauth2/token
          refreshUrl: https://your-host.com/oauth2/token
          scopes:
            openid: openid scope
            offline: offline scope
```